# Error on Heroku after changing username on github

Tags: github, heroku

Firstly, this may not be tied to the username change, but it seems like the most likely cause.

I'm trying to update code on my heroku app after changing my username on Github.  I'm getting the following after pushing to Heroku.

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/appname.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Could you try running the command to `git pull` first?

Comment: It responds with "Already up to date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git pull` would, by default, pull from `origin` (which might refer to GitHub), not `heroku`.

Check your remotes with:

```
git remote -v
```

Try a `git pull heroku`

Comment: git pull heroku master

did it.  I was definitely focused on fixing a problem that wasn't there.  Thank you kindly.

Comment: @ThomasWilson Great! Glad to have be of assistance on this one.